# Sorting database row multiple times

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort a database row(array) 2 times using php. First sorting one column then a second sort within the first sorts arrangement.

I have a row stored in $result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1020
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1008
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1010
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1001
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1018
        )
}
```

I first sort brand, order is not necessary but I just need to group together, I receive a sorted result like

```
Array
(
    [4] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1018
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1020
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1010
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1008
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1001
        )
}
```

Now I need to sort by row key in ascending order but within each brand, The result I want would look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1020
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1010
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [brand] => nike
            [product] => 1018
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1008
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [brand] => adidas
            [product] => 1001
        )
}
```

I have managed to achieve this result like so

```
$result = original row unaltered/sorted

//create brand array for column data also preserving row key

foreach($rows as $array => $row)
{
    $brand[$array] = $row['brand'];
}

//sort_natural here irrelevant, this is just to group together brands

arsort($brand, SORT_NATURAL);

$brand_count = array_count_values($brand);
$unique_brands = array_unique($brand);

//I separate the brand array by each brand, whilst also maintaining row keys, and put them in a multidimensional array

foreach($unique_brands as $key => $value)
{
       $i = 1;
       while($i <= $brand_count[$value])
       {
            $sorted_brands[$value][key($brand)] = current($brand);
            next($brand);
            $i++;
       }
}

//sort row keys we preserved which represent the original row ascendingly

foreach($sorted_brands as $key => $value)
    ksort($sorted_brands[$key], SORT_ASC);

//now I put all this back into 1 array

foreach($sorted_brands as $multi)
    foreach($multi as $key => $value)
        $final[$key] = $value;
```

This now leaves us with result

```
Array
(
    [0] => nike
    [2] => nike
    [4] => nike
    [1] => adidas
    [3] => adidas
)
```

I now create a new array using these keys for the order and also for referencing the old original array to load the corresponding values

```
foreach($final as $key => $value)
    $complete[$key] = $result[$key];
```

This procudes the desired result, but with all this being said, I am wondering if their is a much simpler and easier way to achieve this, I attempted achieving this outcome with functions such as array_multisort,array_column,array_values and some others and could not get anywhere.

Thanks in advance for advice/help.

Comment: why don't you sort on the database query? something like "SELECT (...) ORDER BY brand, id asc"

Comment: I can achieve that result like you said, But I am curios if there are alternative ways like my suggestion but more simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Because your rows of data have the same structure and size, you can just call `sort()` ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Dg8kd))

```
sort($array);
var_export($array);
```

This alphabetizes the rows by `brand` value first, then `product` value second.